# Function of ‘The Avatar’s Apprentice’ in Jack Vance’s “Demon Princes” series

Tags: jack-vance, demon-princes

*Demon Princes* (1964–1981) by Jack Vance is a series of five science fiction novels, linked by a revenge plot. Most chapters are headed by fictional quotations, in the manner of Asimov’s *Foundation* series and similar works. The relevance of these quotations to the novels is usually straightforward, for example some contain background material from fictional reference works like “*Handbook to the Planets*”, and others represent news and current affairs related to the plot. However, each of the five novels in the series has one chapter headed by a quotation from the fictional story ‘The Avatar’s Apprentice’, for example:

> From *The Avatar’s Apprentice, in Scroll from the Ninth Dimension*:
>
> > Intelligence? asked Marmaduke at one of the permitted intervals, as he attended the EMINENCE upon the Parapet. What is intelligence?
> >
> > Why, responded the EMINENCE, it is no more than a human occupation; an activity which men put their brains to, as a frog kicks his legs to swim; it is a standard which men in their egotism use to measure other and perhaps nobler races, who are thereby dumbfounded.
>
> <sub>Jack Vance (1964). [*The Star King*, chapter 11](https://archive.org/details/Galaxy_v22n03_1964-02/page/n177/mode/2up). In *Galaxy* (February 1964), p. 179.</sub>

The five extracts we get over the course of the series suggest that ‘The Avatar’s Apprentice’ resembles a story from Vance’s *The Dying Earth* (1950), but with the stylistic grotesquerie turned up to eleven. The quotations grow to considerable length: the one at the head of chapter 15 of *The Book of Dreams* (1981) is four pages long.

What is the function of the quotations from ‘The Avatar’s Apprentice’ in the *Demon Princes* series? Do they reflect or comment on the themes and plots of the novels? If so, how?

Comment: I think this is a great question, and I wish I had an answer. I haven't read the books in more than a decade, but I hope to return to them soon and share my thoughts on this.